# Remove div content if width of site is less than x px

Tags: javascript, html, css

how can i remove all content of a div if the webpage is only X px width
i am searching for something like this

```html
 <div if(min-width:1000)
{content=''}>
<img>
<script>
....
</script>
</div>
```

Thank you for your answers

Comment: read about media queries. Basically a way to apply css depending on screen size. Then css `display: none` will do the trick of removing the element.

Comment: use media queries

Comment: Please don't use snippets for pseudo code (try clicking on Run code snippet and see what happens).

Comment: Welcome the the internet. May I suggest you discover the wonderful world of **Search Engines**!! Next time try searching out your question. I searched your exact title and found at least 5 answer in 5 seconds.

Comment: media query is the best solution. Also, have look to bootstrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **media query** to achieve this.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px){        
    div{
       display: none;
    }
}
```

The above css snippet will hide the div if the width is less the 1000px.

Comment: _"hide the div"_ - no it will hide _all_ `div`s.

Comment: If you want to hide specific div then use class or id instead of "div" in css